# Substring Regular Expression for occurence

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to select part of the string which occurs after the first underline _ and before the second, third or whatever amount of underlines _ occur in a string.

For example I have strings such as:

```
75618_LORIK1_2_BABA_ODD_GENERIC
19_GENTRIT3_CC_DD_FF_BROWSERTC
75618_BETIM2
```

Output should be:

```
LORIK1
GENTRIT3
BETIM2
```

I cant seem to find some kind of expression of substring to get that part, I tried using:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLNAME, 0, INSTR(COLNAME, '_')-1) FROM DUAL;
```

But it seems to get only the part before the first occurrence of '_'.

Comment: What do you mean by "and before the second, third or whatever ..."? That makes no sense. Do you mean "and before the second underline, or to the end of the string if there is only one underline"? Then - what if there is no underline in the entire string? And finally, is the use of **regular expressions** required? That is not the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: @mathguy one thing I know string wont ever be only _, as shown in the example that is the string format and I've already shown the output. As far as I can see there are two approaches to this, using a combination of Substr Instr or by regular expression of which I don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do this with regular expressions.

```
with
  test_data (str) as (
    select '75618_LORIK1_2_BABA_ODD_GENERIC' from dual union all
    select '19_GENTRIT3_CC_DD_FF_BROWSERTC'  from dual union all
    select '75618_BETIM2'                    from dual union all
    select 'NO UNDERLINES HERE'              from dual
  )
select str, regexp_substr(str, '[^_]*', 1, 3) as second_token
from   test_data
;

STR                             SECOND_TOKEN                   
------------------------------- -------------------------------
75618_LORIK1_2_BABA_ODD_GENERIC LORIK1                         
19_GENTRIT3_CC_DD_FF_BROWSERTC  GENTRIT3                       
75618_BETIM2                    BETIM2                         
NO UNDERLINES HERE
```